# How to create hyper text link between two mysql tables through php

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

First of all, sorry because I'm not sure if the question I'm doing has to do with what is called "relations" in mysql (I'm not an expert).

Well the thing is that from a PHP I do a query to call a table stored at a mysql db, let's say:

```
+-------+-----+
|NAME   |YEAR |
+-------+-----+
|Ana    |1990 |
|John   |1987 |
|Jane   |1992 |
+-------+-----+
```

and I have a second table in mysql, let's say this one:

```
+-------+----------+
|NAME   |CITY      |
+-------+----------+
|Ana    |Barcelona |
|John   |Santiago  |
|Jane   |La Habana |
+-------+----------+
```

so what I need to do is, at the first table that I see through PHP, have the name clickable so if I click Ana, obtain at a second PHP page:

"Ana is in Barcelona"

Sorry if I'm too naive to express myself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the first set of data through a MySQL query, then create a link to a second page (by either posting or getting the variables) to lookup the next set of data.

Simple MySQL queries, really.

Comment: Sorry my friend, I'm not an expert, could you give a more detailed advice, I hardly understand what you say.

Comment: If you want to show this table to someone on a frontend like a web page, you will need to use PHP to request this data from the database. Read up on MySQL queries, and use this to produce an array you can form the first table from. Afterwards, use a similar approach to produce the second one. Please remember Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a tutorial nor individual help site. There is heaps of intro tutorials to MySQL queries on the web.

Answer (score 0):

While printing `Anna` in page1, make a link to page2 and send `Anna` using `GET`.
Make link as `<a href=page2.php?name=Anna>Anna</a>`. This data is available to page2 and can be accessed using the `GET` global array as `$_GET['name']`.Now you can create your query easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html) in the query you display the first results:

```
SELECT myFirstTable.name, myFirstTable.year, mySecondTable.city FROM myFirstTable LEFT JOIN ON mySecondTable.name=myFirstTable.name WHERE 1
```

Then on your php you can assign the third result to the page you want to show.

Comment: Thanks Luis, I have tried your solutions, my actual query is this one I have tried in phpmyadim but it does not work: SELECT Bibliografias.Traductor, TradBiograficos.Nombre FROM Bibliografias LEFT JOIN ON TradBiograficos.Nombre=Bibliografias.Traductor WHERE Traductor LIKE 'A%' GROUP BY `Traductor`  The error I get is this:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON TradBiograficos.Nombre=Bibliografias.Traductor WHERE Traductor LIKE 'A%' GROU' at line 1

Comment: Based on the manual you linked me, I changed the query to this: SELECT Traductor FROM Bibliografias LEFT JOIN TradBiograficos ON TradBiograficos.Nombre = Bibliografias.Traductor WHERE Traductor LIKE 'A%' GROUP BY `Traductor` this gives me back the list of translators but I think what you say in here "Then on your php you can assign the third result to the page you want to show", is what I'm lacking (maybe).

Comment: I've tried this other one with same results: SELECT Bibliografias.Traductor FROM Bibliografias LEFT JOIN TradBiograficos ON Bibliografias.Traductor = TradBiograficos.Nombre WHERE Nombre LIKE 'A%' GROUP BY `Nombre`

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer you before, but was out of town. Ok, in your first query, in the WHERE clause you put `WHERE Traductor LIKE 'A%'`. You're getting an error, because you're not putting the table name, instead use `table.field` notation. So the correct query would be `SELECT Bibliografias.Traductor, TradBiograficos.Nombre FROM Bibliografias LEFT JOIN ON TradBiograficos.Nombre=Bibliografias.Traductor WHERE Bibliografias.Traductor LIKE 'A%' GROUP BY Bibliografias.Traductor`